# JSX css to inline styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I am working with React, and I need to be able to take an css object literal and convert it to a string. React automatically does this for style objects added to the style tag. Is there a function in React, or another library, that you can use to convert object literals to css strings?

For Example, I need to take a literal that looks like:

```
{
  fontSize: '4em',
  zIndex: 2,
  marginLeft: '-.5em'
}
```

And convert it to a css string:

```
"font-size: 4em; z-index: 2, margin-left: -.5em"
```

What is the best tool to use for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with `react-style-object-to-css`

[react-style-object-to-css](https://github.com/Calvin92/react-style-object-to-css)

Answer (score 3):

here's a dead-simple ES5 conversion routine for browsers:

```
function o2s(o){ 
  var elm=new Option(); 
  Object.assign(elm.style, o);
  return elm.style.cssText; 
}

// test/usage:
o2s({
  fontSize: '4em',
  zIndex: 2,
  marginLeft: '-.5em'
});

// == "font-size: 4em; z-index: 2; margin-left: -0.5em;"
```

this approach also self-validates the CSS rules and works with any known vendor prefixes and non-standard properties.

A request was made for the opposite, which is also easy if you ride atop native tools:

```
function s2o(s){
 var elm=new Option;
 elm.style.cssText=s;
 return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(elm.style).filter(x=>x[1] && !(x[0]-1.1)));
}

// test/usage:
s2o("font-size: 4em; z-index: 2; margin-left: -0.5em;")
/* == {
    "fontSize": "4em",
    "marginLeft": "-0.5em",
    "zIndex": "2"
} */
```

Comment: What about the reverse operation? Converting string to react style object

Comment: @Vadorequest: ask and you shall receive. 5 years or less guarantee...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/apeman-react-style

You can choose whether or not to return it as a string literal or style object data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually I was looking for a function, not a react component. I want to convert an object of styles to a string with a function.